# Send a `ENTER` key stroke to pipe in Makefile

Tags: git, makefile, credentials

I'm trying to pass my git credential into a command in my `Makefile` via a shell script.

My command looks like:

```
local.test:
   mycommand --envs GIT_USER_NAME=$(cmd to retrieve local user name) --envs GIT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(cmd to retrieve PAT)
```

The command to retrieve git credential is simple when using terminal

```
git credential-osxkeychain get
```

However, this command is expecting a key stroke of `ENTER` after it's fired, otherwise it will just wait with a blinking cursor indefinitely.

My question is now, how do I send this `ENTER` key stroke to the Make command programatically so I can just run `make local.test` without issue

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: `printf '\n' | git credential-osxkeychain get`?

Comment: That simple! Thank you, @RenaudPacalet. You are my constant source of answer when coming to Makefile/shell/bash questions.